# Undefined Reference To yywrap

Tags: flex-lexer

I have a simple "language" that I'm using Flex(Lexical Analyzer), it's like this:

```
/* Just like UNIX wc */
%{
int chars = 0;
int words = 0;
int lines = 0;
%}

%%
[a-zA-Z]+ { words++; chars += strlen(yytext); }
\n        { chars++; lines++; }
.         { chars++; }
%%

int main()
{
    yylex();
    printf("%8d%8d%8d\n", lines, words, chars);
}
```

The I run a `flex count.l`, all goes ok without errors or warnings, then when I try to do a `cc lex.yy.c` I got this errors:

> ubuntu@eeepc:~/Desktop$ cc lex.yy.c
>   /tmp/ccwwkhvq.o: In function `yylex':
>   lex.yy.c:(.text+0x402): undefined reference to`yywrap'
>   /tmp/ccwwkhvq.o: In function `input':
>   lex.yy.c:(.text+0xe25): undefined reference to`yywrap'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

**What is wrong?**

Answer (score 153, accepted):

The scanner calls this function on end of file, so you can point it to another file and continue scanning its contents. If you don't need this, use

```
%option noyywrap
```

in the scanner specification.

Although disabling `yywrap`  is certainly the best option, it may also be possible to link with `-lfl` to use the default `yywrap()` function in the library `fl` (i.e. `libfl.a`) provided by flex. Posix requires that library to be available with the linker flag `-ll` and the default OS X install only provides that name.

Comment: Exactly where is '%option noyywrap' to be added, please?
In the definition section or on the command line?

Comment: I added it to the beginning of the `.l` file and `lex` accepted it! I am not sure if that is the best place. Maybe it doesn't matter.

Comment: It's supposed to be in the options section, between the first `%}` and `%%`.

Answer (score 15):

I prefer to define my own yywrap(). I'm compiling with C++, but the point should be obvious. If someone calls the compiler with multiple source files, I store them in a list or array, and then yywrap() is called at the end of each file to give you a chance to continue with a new file.

```
int yywrap() {
   // open next reference or source file and start scanning
   if((yyin = compiler->getNextFile()) != NULL) {
      line = 0; // reset line counter for next source file
      return 0;
   }
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: Hello @codenheim I tried adding your suggested yywrap() function but got an error: "compiler undeclared"

Answer (score 6):

```
int yywrap(){return(1);}
```

use this code at the end of the program..Simple

Answer (score 4):

flex doesn't always install with its development libraries (which is odd, as it is a development tool).  Install the libraries, and life is better.

On Redhat base systems:

```
yum -y install flex-devel
./configure && make
```

On Debian based systems

```
sudo apt-get install libfl-dev
```

Comment: What is the equivalent for arch ?

Answer (score 3):

As a note for followers, flex 2.6.3 has a bug where libfl.a "typically would" define yywrap but then doesn't in certain instances, so check if that's your version of flex, might be related to your problem:

https://github.com/westes/flex/issues/154