# Undefined Reference To yywrap()

Tags: compiler-errors

Wrote the following code in flex and c file has generated but compiler shows "undefined reference to 'yywrap' " error.

```
%{
int nchar;
int nline;
%}
%%
[\n] {nline++;}
. {nchar++;}
%%
void main(void){
yylex();
printf("%d%d,nchar,nline");
}
```

Questions like this have been asked and all the answers were based on ignoring yywrap function like adding
    #define yywrap() 1
Which in this case the program runs but doesn't work but I want it to work.

Comment: There is a reference to `yywrap` in your code that will not link. Did you define it? Are you using a version that doesn't automatically define a stub definition? If you don't want to suppress `yywrap` you might have to define it or update Flex.

Comment: I use flex-2.5.4a-1-bin version. how should I update it? I also tried other versions but the error was not fixed.i did not define yywrap!

Comment: The easiest thing is to define a stub definition. That is, if you don't actually need a `yywrap()`, create a no-op. You said you did some research, but many of the answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811125/undefined-reference-to-yywrap apply here. Are you using the `-lfl` linker option, for example?

Comment: I don't know what is    -lf1  I need yywrap() because I want to work correctly the exe file that Is produced after compiling

Comment: Did you read those answers? They explain what you have to do. `-lfl` will ask the linker to link in a default reference. If a stubbed yywrap is causing a problem that is a different problem that you need to solve. You _need_ to provide a ref to `yywrap`, either implicitly or explicitly (or set the `noyywrap` option if you don't want it at all.)

Comment: It sounds like your real question is related to a problem that you get after stubbing out or configuring out `yywrap` from your code, which is a different problem than reported here. The linking issue you report is addressed by the Linked QA. I advise resubmitting your question so the real problem can be discussed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined Reference To yywrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811125/undefined-reference-to-yywrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define it yourself like this:

```
int yywrap() {  
// open next reference or source file and start scanning  
if((yyin = compiler->getNextFile()) != NULL) {  
  line = 0; // reset line counter for next source file
  return 0;  
   }
return 1;
}
```

Or decide not to use it:

```
    %option noyywrap
```

Or install it; which is like this for a redhat-based os:

```
    yum -y install flex-devel
    ./configure && make
```

Comment: Where exactly does one add 

    `%option noyywrap`?