# Is it posible to compile Flex/Lex on a M1 Mac

Tags: c, macos, apple-m1, lex

In my compilers class we are writting Flex/Lex code. When I compiled the `.l` file and tried to compile the resultant `lex.yy.c` file with gcc, I got the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_yywrap", referenced from:
      _yylex in lex-fb85c9.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Does is posible to compile it in a Apple Silicon (M1) Mac, at least in a Linux VM?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1811125/undefined-reference-to-yywrap

Comment: @SteveFriedl's link is a reasonable duplicate except that on a default flex install on macOS, you would need to use `-ll` rather than `-lfl`. `%option noyywrap` is a better solution.

Comment: Yes sorry, I have been busy these weeks and I haven't seen the answers before. The @rici solution and yours worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a test file and compiled:

```
% flex lex.l
% cc -o lex lex.yy.c -lc -ll
% grep 'yylex();' lex.yy.c
    yylex();
```

The `-ll` on the `cc` command links against the `libl` library. Current M1 based macOS does not provide a `libfl` library you may see referenced.